# Ended up posting the same question on the 3 sites. Hope it is not that bad!

Tags: support, new-users, stack-exchange

After posting a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499484/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-mac-os-x-to-virtualbox-vms-using-host-only), which was the only one I knew before, I saw that there was Server Fault. Since my issue was not dev related but platform related, I [reposted it on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/125337/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-mac-os-x-to-virtualbox-vms-using-host-only). But then someone on Stack Overflow advised that it should be posted on Super User. The Stack Overflow team took care of [migrating the question](https://superuser.com/questions/123290/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-mac-os-x-to-virtualbox-vms-using-host-only).
Asking to forgive the newb error :)

Comment: You can even associate your accounts on the 3 sites (4 actually with meta included) on the accounts tab of your profile (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145165?tab=accounts#tab-top)

Comment: Not entirely your fault, you were also badly advised. They told you to ask it on other site, which they shouldn't do. They should have told you about the migration system, and about creating and associating your accounts on the destination site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgiven. Now go and spread the joy and word of all that it is the mighty Trilogy :)

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb:

- Programming related? Ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- Computer related, and the computer with the problem is not your personal computer but rather you are administering it for someone else? [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)
- Computer related, and the computer is your PC? [Super User](http://superuser.com)